# Can't solve declaration and loop errors in C++ building with Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

My project won't build because of these two errors, and I have not been able to figure out how to fix them. One of them I thought was related to my version of GCC/G++, but I have 4.7 and I'm pretty sure c++ 11 along with it. I'm not sure about the other "it" declaration error.

My code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void encrypt(std::string &iostr, int key) {
key %= 26;
int ch;

for (auto &it : iostr) {
ch = tolower(it);
if (!islower(ch)) {
continue;
}
ch += key;
if (ch > 'z') {
ch -= 26;
}
it = ch;
}
}

int main() {
string source;
int key = 1;
cout
<< "Paste cyphertext and press enter to shift each letter right 1";

getline(cin, source);
encrypt(source, key);

cout << source << "";

encrypt(source, key);
cout << source << endl;
cout << "Press ENTER to exit";
cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() + 1);

return 0;

}
```

Errors:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void encrypt(std::string&, int)’:
test.cpp:10:13: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘it’ with no type   
[-fpermissive]
test.cpp:10:18: error: range-based ‘for’ loops are not allowed in C++98 mode
```

What's going on with these errors, and how can I fix them? Thanks in advance for help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: What is your compiler command line? Are you using `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Now I'm getting a ton of these errors after using that command, werid: "make all Building target: New Invoking: GCC C++ Linker g++ -o "New" ./test.o ./test.o: In function encrypt(std::string&, int)': /home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:10: undefined reference to std::string::begin()' /home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:10: undefined reference to std::string::end()' ./test.o: In function main': /home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:24: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'"

Comment: @bert0nius Why are you using `#include "stdafx.h"` in a program that is compiled with g++?  That header file is not necessary, as it is a Visual Studio-centric header file that is only used for precompiled headers.  And why is your `using namespace std;` put in a topsy-turvy place in your file?  That line should come after you've #included the necessary standard header files, not before them.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill That windows call was removed and I changed the order of using namespace std; to after the includes, but the same undefined reference errors remain. Any idea what could be going on? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need compiler option `-std=c++11`.

And comment your first header file since you are using gcc, I think it is Windows specific:

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
```

Comment: I get this: "make all 
Building target: New
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "New"  ./test.o   
./test.o: In function `encrypt(std::string&, int)':
/home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:10: undefined reference to `std::string::begin()'
/home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:10: undefined reference to `std::string::end()'
./test.o: In function `main':
/home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:24: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'"  And it goes on like that with many "undefined reference" errors. Not sure.

Comment: check your include path in make file

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
error: range-based ‘for’ loops are not allowed in C++98 mode
```

is clear indication that you are using g++ in C++98 mode.

Use the command line option `-std=c++11` to compile using C++11 mode.

Comment: Now I'm getting a ton of these errors, werid: "make all 
Building target: New
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "New"  ./test.o   
./test.o: In function `encrypt(std::string&, int)':
/home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:10: undefined reference to `std::string::begin()'
/home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:10: undefined reference to `std::string::end()'
./test.o: In function `main':
/home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:24: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'"